# RetroPi on B+ - Slowness, music glitches when WiFi connected

Tags: wifi, performance, retropie

I have a B+ with retropie 2.3 installed.
I've sucessfuly connected a TP-Link TL-WN722N WiFi dongle.

It seems that most roms run slower and have music glitches when dongle is connected. When I disconnect the WiFi dongle they perform smoother.
Tested on NES/SNES/GENESIS emulators, multiple roms.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any suggested solution or a lead to the cause?

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? Have you tested the voltage available at the test points?

Comment: A very interesting question @SteveRobillard. It's powered by a dedicated USB charger claiming 1.2A and 5V. Too low?

Comment: Many chargers don't put out what they claim. Have a look at this http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems