# RetroArch Skips Random Frames in RetroPie

Tags: emulation, retropie

everyone! I recently bought a Raspberry Pi B+ and was able to install RetroPie/EmulationStation straight from the RetroPie-Setup script with no trouble at all.

All seems well until I start playing either an NES or Sega Genesis game for a little bit. I kept my screen resolution low and overclocked my Pi to the Medium setting to ensure I stay at 60fps, yet every five to ten seconds the game slows down for half a second then picks up again.

I have a feeling this is a RetroArch-specific issue because MAME4Pi works perfectly fine. I tried toying with the video and audio settings in RetroArch, but nothing worked.

Is there something I haven't tried or should I just overclock further?

**Edit**: After reading this question: ([RetroPi on B+ - Slowness, music glitches when WiFi connected](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/retropi-on-b-slowness-music-glitches-when-wifi-connected?rq=1)), it seems like my WiFi dongle is causing most of the slow-down. The frame skipping is not nearly as bad, but it still happens at times. Is there something I could try?